# display a pdf from a handler inside an iframe

Tags: html, asp.net, pdf, iframe

I have a page that should display a `pdf` document served by a handler I created.

it is set as follows:

```
<div id="iframeContainer" runat="server" style="width: 500px; background: #ffa2a2">
     <p>pdf placeHolder</p>
     <iframe id="iframeTag" runat="server"></iframe>
</div>
```

and I use the following code behind to set the `src` attribute.

```
this.iframeTag.Attributes["src"] = HandlerUrl;
```

when I inspect the element I see that the Iframe returns a blank `HTML` document:

```
<iframe id="iframeTag">
  <html>
     <head></head>
     <body></body>
  </html>
</iframe>
```

When I put in the address in the html code `src` attribute it works well.

any suggestions on how to correct this?

Comment: Does your debugger hits the handler ? Did you debug it ? Is there any error javascript or other ? Check out network if handler is being invoked ? Can you post your handler URL ?

Comment: the handler works well and i can see the document in the browser.

Comment: Thank you for your help, i have solved this issue. it turns out there was a problem in the code behind logic.